# MATLAB : How to replace numbers in a single column of a cell with corresponding strings?

Tags: matlab

I have a 50000 * 2 cell with number contents. Now I want to replace the second column which has numbers ranging from 1 to 10 with corresponding strings like 'airplane' for 1, 'automobile' for 2 and so on. What is the most efficient method for this?
I tried first by splitting the second column content to a new cell classes1 and coverted it to strings and tried replacing by applying the code below :

```
classes1(strcmp('1',classes1))={'airplane'};
classes1(strcmp('2',classes1))={'automobile'};
classes1(strcmp('3',classes1))={'bird'};
classes1(strcmp('4',classes1))={'cat'};
classes1(strcmp('5',classes1))={'deer'};
classes1(strcmp('6',classes1))={'dog'};
classes1(strcmp('7',classes1))={'frog'};
classes1(strcmp('8',classes1))={'horse'};
classes1(strcmp('9',classes1))={'ship'};
classes1(strcmp('10',classes1))={'truck'};
```

But that was not successfull. It only replaced '10' with 'truck'.

UPDATE : This code will actually work. But in my case strings ' 1' has to be used instead '1' (a space was missing).

Comment: Your code works for me... is there something different about your single digit number maybe? like `' 1'` or `'01'` for example?

Comment: I see, let me check that. :D

Comment: @Dan : Thankyou, actually I replaced '1' with ' 1', 2 with ' 2' and so on. It worked. Should I delete this question?

Comment: don't delete it, the answers still help you since they show you how to accomplish this without doing it so manually.

Comment: Ok Dan, I am not deleting it and the answers are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to extend to your big case -

```
%%// Create look up and numeral data cell arrays for demo
LOOKUP_CELL_ARRAY = {'airplane','automobile','chopper'};
IN_CELL_ARRAY = num2cell(round(1+2.*rand(10,2)))

%%// Replace the second column of data cell array with corresponding
%%// strings in the look up array
IN_CELL_ARRAY(:,2)= LOOKUP_CELL_ARRAY(cell2mat(IN_CELL_ARRAY(:,2)))
```

Output -

```
IN_CELL_ARRAY = 

    [2]    [2]
    [2]    [2]
    [2]    [1]
    [2]    [2]
    [3]    [1]
    [2]    [3]
    [1]    [1]
    [3]    [3]
    [2]    [2]
    [2]    [3]


IN_CELL_ARRAY = 

    [2]    'automobile'
    [2]    'automobile'
    [2]    'airplane'  
    [2]    'automobile'
    [3]    'airplane'  
    [2]    'chopper'   
    [1]    'airplane'  
    [3]    'chopper'   
    [2]    'automobile'
    [2]    'chopper'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows with `cellfun`:

```
% replacement strings
R = {'airplane','automobile','bird','cat','deer', ...
     'dog','frog','horse','ship','truck'};

% example data
nums = randi(10,100,1);
data(:,1) = num2cell(nums)
data(:,2) = cellstr(num2str(nums))

data = 

    [ 3]    ' 3'
    [ 1]    ' 1'
    [ 1]    ' 1'
    [ 8]    ' 8'
    [ 8]    ' 8'
    [ 8]    ' 8'
    [ 7]    ' 7'
    [ 9]    ' 9'
    [ 1]    ' 1'
    ...
```

`str2double(x)` does not care about whether its `'01'` or `'1'`:

```
% replicate number strings with strings
data(:,2) = cellfun(@(x) R( str2double(x) ), data(:,2) )


data = 

    [ 3]    'bird'      
    [ 1]    'airplane'  
    [ 1]    'airplane'  
    [ 8]    'horse'     
    [ 8]    'horse'     
    [ 8]    'horse'     
    [ 7]    'frog'      
    [ 9]    'ship'      
    [ 1]    'airplane'   
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just with indexing:

```
data = {'aa' 1
        'bb' 3
        'cc' 2
        'dd' 6
        'ee' 1
        'ff' 5}; %// example data: two-col cell array, 2nd col is numbers
str = {'airplane','automobile','bird','cat','deer', ...
       'dog','frog','horse','ship','truck'}; %// replacement strings

data(:,2) = str(vertcat(data{:,2})); %// do the replacing
```